# C# Google Drive API Error " Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer' does not contain a definition for 'Authenticator' "

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am trying a sample code with domain wide delegation of authority.  I am implementing the code specified in this link: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation

```
    private DriveService GetService(String userEmail)
    {

        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        var provider = new AssertionFlowClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, certificate)
        {
            ServiceAccountId = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
            Scope = DriveService.Scope.Drive.GetStringValue(),
            ServiceAccountUser = userEmail,
        };

        authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(provider, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);


        return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { Authenticator = authenticator, ApplicationName = "sample" });

    }
```

When i compile it i am getting an error saying "'Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer' does not contain a definition for 'Authenticator' ". i think its because of a recent change to the API. So can someone please suggest as to how to overcome this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to recomend you use the Google dot net client library.

**NuGet command**

```
PM> Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v2
```

**Sample code:**

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;  

var serviceAccountEmail = "539621478859-imkdv94bgujcom228h3ea33kmkoefhil@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
ServiceAccountCredential certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\dev\GoogleDriveServiceAccount\key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
           {
               Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));

// Create the service.
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
        });
```

All your requests are then run though service.   If you din't already make sure that you have both the `Drive API and Drive SDK` selected in your developer console application application.

Comment: @DalmTo The fix u suggested is working. But with the "OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>" object i used to call the "ApplyAuthenticationToRequest" function on web requests. So now which object should i use for this call?

Comment: not sure I understand that question.  Pop into http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54591/google-apis if your still on

Comment: i mean to ask now which object should i use to call the function "ApplyAuthenticationToRequest". 'HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            //authenticator.ApplyAuthenticationToRequest(request);

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            System.IO.Stream received = response.GetResponseStream();'

Comment: Why do you want to call that?  you have authentication in Credential already, you have a drive service object what more do you need?  http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c/

Comment: @DaImTo, your answer really helps! Thanks.   However, there is a minor error in your code:  "ServiceAccountCredential certificate =  new X509Certificate2(.... ",    the type of certificate variable is not right.   should be   " var certificate = ....